# Bar Graph Arrangement using 3 bar per Day D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, d3.js, svg

Using D3.JS

I have a running Bar Graph sample in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/297nLaby/)

This is composed of 3 `rect` per Day.
First is the black one, seconds is the blue one and the third is the orange.

My problem is to just to arrange the graph with its designated location.

Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @ rioV8 sori for that. The `Grouped` is just composed of 1 out of 3 bar.

Comment: This is just my first time using custom bar graph.

Comment: Just use the "Grouped Bar Chart" example, change the data set and colors and Bob-is-your-uncle

Comment: Good Idea thanks.. @rioV8